# How do I know what the cement or stucco finish on my house is?

Tags: cement, stucco

Just purchased a house (first time homeowner) and I'm realizing there is of course a lot I don't know about it.  I'm trying to hang a mailbox on what I think is a stucco wall, but apparently there are many different types (and some of the potential fasteners I'm considering say to only use them for certain types of stucco (like synthetic, mortar, and some others - Portland?).

Our home inspection simply says "stucco" and the wall is very smooth and a white/light gray color.

How can I tell what kind of stucco it is (assuming it is stucco) and if whatever anchors/screws I'm looking at are appropriate?

Comment: I am not quite sure what “synthetic” would mean unless some add mix for increased strength and water resistance. Some walls are just vapor barrier mesh (anything from chicken wire to expanded steel) then several coats of stucco. Some homes have sheeting behind the vapor barrier. I like toggle bolts on stucco as they spread out the force on the wall expanding anchors I think are a waste but may work if it is a some what low profile (only 3-4” thick) if the box is where it will get wet make sure to run a bead of calking above each of the screws to keep any water out that drips in the back.

Comment: How old is the house? Can you post a picture of it? One showing a good portion of a wall including a window or door maybe 8 -12 ft away and another close up where the window or door meets the wall just a few feet away